# Show that $N(f)= \inf\{\|g\|_p+\|h\|_q;f=g+h, g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}), h \in L^q(\mathbb{R})\}$ is a norm on $L^p(\mathbb{R})+L^q(\mathbb{R}) $

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, convolution, interpolation

Define $N(f)= \inf\{\|g\|_p+\|h\|_q;f=g+h, g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}), h \in L^q(\mathbb{R})\}$.

I want to prove that $N$ is a norm on $L^p(\mathbb{R})+L^q(\mathbb{R})$ but I can't prove  that $N(f)=0 $ implies $f= 0$.

Could this result be proved without a further hypothesis? (Such as "compatibility” assumption...). Could you please prove or give me some references for the proof of this result? I was trying to prove it but there is no progress.

After that, we have $L^p(\mathbb{R})+L^q(\mathbb{R})$ with $N$  is a Banach space since $(L^p(\mathbb{R}), \|.\|_p)$ and $(L^q(\mathbb{R}), \|.\|_q)$ are Banach spaces. Is this correct?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You won't be able to prove that without a continuity assumption. A function that vanishes everywhere except at one point has $N(f)=0$ yet is not zero.

Comment: Could you please give me a more clearly suggestion of continuity assumption?

Comment: I mean assume that $f$ is continuous. Otherwise you will only be able to prove that $f$ is zero almost everywhere - but I just realised that you may be assuming that implicitly already.

Comment: You're welcome. Does my answer below make sense to you?

Comment: Yes of course. But, are you think this result can be proved with other assumption, not compatibility assumption?

Comment: It's not really an assumption since it is *true*.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence converges in $L^{p}$ then there is a subsequence which converges almost everywhere. $N(f)=0$ implies there exist sequences $\{g_n\} \subset L^{p}$,$\{h_n\} \subset L^{q}$ such that $f=g_n+h_n$ , $||g_n||_p \to 0$ and $||h_n||_q\to 0$. First choose a subsequence along which $\{g_n\} \to 0$. Then look at the corresponding subsequence of $\{h_n\}$ and get a subsequence which $\to 0$ a.e.. By doing this we get one sequence $\{n_k\}$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $\{g_{n_k}\} \to 0$ and $\{h_{n_k}\} \to 0$. Since $f=g_{n_k}+g_{n_k}$ for each k we get $f=0$ a.e. which means f is the zero element of $L^{p}+L^{q}$.

Answer (score 0):

You had a very good intuition when you mentioned a compatibility assumption.

A precise result regarding how to norm a sum of vector spaces is given [in this article](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjT-5H_tL7ZAhUCbFAKHcCmBMIQFghVMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.univ-toulouse.fr%2F%7Ejbhu%2FWhen%2520is%2520Lr%2520contained....pdf&usg=AOvVaw2uywx_wKbruXQgcEChSWQt). Namely, the norm is what you say, and the compatibility assumption is that

> For all sequences $f_k$ in $L^p+L^q$, if
>
> - $f_k$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$
> - $f_k$ converges to $\tilde f$ in $L^q$
>
> then $f=\tilde f$.

Note that in your case it is implicit that "$=$" means "equal almost everywhere". In the same article it is explained that for $L^p$ and $L^q$ this compatibility does occur, since convergence in any $L^r$ implies convergence almost everywhere after passing to a subsequence.

Comment: @Dap absolutely, thanks - fixed.